# How to POST a DateTime value to a Web API 2 controller

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I have an example controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Example")]
public class ExampleController : ApiController
{
    [Route("Foo")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string Foo([FromUri] string startDate)
    {
        return "This is working";
    }

    [Route("Bar")]
    [HttpPost]
    public string Bar([FromBody] DateTime startDate)
    {
        return "This is not working";
    }
}
```

When I issue a GET request to: `http://localhost:53456/api/Example/Foo?startDate=2016-01-01` it works.

When I POST to `http://localhost:53456/api/Example/Bar` I receive a `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` error.

This is my POST data:

```
{
"startDate":"2016-01-01T00:00:00.0000000-00:00"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you posting this ? Can you share the code ?

Comment: @Shyju That is basically all the code (see Igor's answer below). I got it working

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't post non-objects directly, you need to wrap them in side an object container when using `FromBody`.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Example")]
public class ExampleController : ApiController
{
    [Route("Foo")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string Foo([FromUri] string startDate)
    {
        return "This is working";
    }

    [Route("Bar")]
    [HttpPost]
    public string Bar([FromBody] BarData data)
    {
        return "This is not working";
    }
}

public class BarData{
    public DateTime startDate {get;set;}
}
```

The other way it *could* work is if you form-encode the value like this using the `=` symbol (*note you are sending it as a non-object, the curly braces have been removed*).

```
"=2016-01-01T00:00:00.0000000-00:00"
```

Comment: That worked! Was hoping to POST a simple date but it seems putting DateTime property inside an object did the trick.

Comment: @PierreNortje - you can also try the form-encoded way but really the best solution is to use a wrapper object (see update at bottom).

Comment: @PierreNortje - also if you find an answer useful please do not forget to mark it as answer and/or up-vote based on what you think is appropriate. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try just POSTing:

```
{
  "2016-01-01T00:00:00.0000000-00:00"
}
```

Specifying the property name would mean your endpoint would need to accept an object with a property named `startDate`. In this case you only want to pass a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 2):

The submitted format of the date is important, and depends on your client library. It must look like this (quotes in the raw body payload):

```
"2015-05-02T00:00:00"
```

No braces, no property names. The format that's transmitted from your code and/or client library is going to depend on whether you're sending a javascript date, or a string representation of one. So, tweak the submissions code appropriately...

Comment: Here's a simple and accurate explanation of parameter binding:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api